# boost tcp async_connect() occasionally fails to connect to a server on the same LAN until until Windows is rebooted

Tags: boost-asio, windows-networking

Our Windows client applications connects to a server on the same LAN via the function `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_connect` like so:

```
std::string ip, port;
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket client( io );

boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint( boost::asio::ip::address::from_string( ip ), port );
// synchronous. (Does not return in problematic case and callback not called)
client.async_connect( endpoint, boost::bind(&CallbackFunction, this, ip, port, boost::asio::placeholders::error ) );
```

Occasionally, and ever so randomly, one client will fails to reach the server no matter how many times the client is restarted. The only solution is to reboot the workstation (Windows 7 or 10). I am at loss as to the reason for this intermittent failure given that the client and server are on the same LAN and other clients on the LAN are able to connect to the server. Could it be some local route that's been cached? If so is there a command that I can run in the terminal to flush the route or release the appropriate system resources.

Comment: Can other clients /on the same machine/ connect? What does nslookup/ping/netcat/nmap say? I suspect network misconfig (like e.g. no DHCP lease or IP conflict)

Comment: @sehe Other workstations running the client can connect and so that the client on the problematic workstation after its been rebooted. The problem crops up randomly on any given client.

Comment: @sehe I cannot run any of the commands you recommended because the workstation has been rebooted. Someone else ran `ping` though and they swore that they could reach the server.